# Reference request concerning splitting fields for groups that are related to special symmetric groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-fields

Denote the symmetric group of order $n!$ by $S_n$. Let $H:=S_p$ for an odd prime $p$.

Every finite field $k$ is a splitting field $(^*)$ for $kH$, in particular $k:=\mathbb{F}_p$.

> Questions:
>
> Is $k:=\mathbb{F}_p$ also a splitting field for $kG$ where
>
> a) $G:=H\times H$ ?
>
> b) $G:=H \wr C_2$ ?

I would be interested in references appearing in the literature which deal with these (similar) questions.

Thank you in advance for the help.

**Remark 1:** $(^*)$ $k$ is a splitting field of $S_n$ if the $k$-algebra $kS_n$ splits over $k$, i.e. if for every simple $kS_n$-module $M$, we have End$_{kSn}(M)\cong k$. (cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422979/splitting-fields-of-symmetric-groups)

**Remark 2:** I looked at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+product+group and due to remark 2.2 there my questions might not have an affirmative answer for arbitrary groups, but I was interested, if the statement is nevertheless true in these special cases.

**Remark 3:** I posted the same question at math.stackexchange.com (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800244/reference-request-concerning-splitting-fields-for-groups-that-are-related-to-spe) more then one week ago, but I did not receive an answer. I hope that it is ok to ask it here now.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If k splits groups G,H then it splits $G\times H$. More generally the tensor product of split finite dimensional algebras is split.

Comment: The result mentioned in the answer to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369932/looking-for-citable-reference-for-a-well-known-fact-about-tensor-product-of-fini certainly covers the case of HxH.   The proof given there will handle the general case.  It all boils down  to the tensor product over k of matrix algebras over k if a matrix algebra over k.